# Angular UI-Grid: How to Clear All (general Angular and built-in UI-Grid) Column Filters On Button Click

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angular-ui-grid

**How do I *clear* AND *refresh* ALL of my (general Angular and built-in UI-Grid) filters on a button click?**

**Background:** I have built an application that uses the UI-Grid and takes advantage of the [built-in filtering functionality](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering). It also has a cross-column search written in angular.

**Current Battle** I want to be able to clear and refresh my filters on a single button click. So far I have been able to implement this for the cross-column search *but have **not** been successful implementing it for the built-in column filters* (which ironically I thought would be the easy part!).

**Research Done On Problem:**

1) Searched through the UI-Grid tutorials ... fail

2) Looked at the provided [UI-Grid API](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi) ...partial success! Seems like I think I found what I'm looking for in the "clearAllFilters" function ([here is the source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/6c9350c/src/js/core/factories/Grid.js#L13)) but I cannot figure out how to implement it so onto step 3...

3) Googled like mad for implementation demos/examples/help/hints/anything!? ...fail

4) Asked for help on Stack Overflow :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you can reset variables the grid is bound to in the controller to their default value?

Comment: @Matt - Yes, what I want to do is reset the variables the column filters are bound to - what you suggest is in line with how I am resetting my angular cross-column search and it's perfect for that but the ui-grid filters are set and maintained within the ui-grid js code and that is what I am having trouble accessing/resetting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't see the clearAllFilters() function of ui grid. So it becomes simpler. You can do this:

```
  $scope.clearFilters = function() {
            $scope.myGridApi.grid.clearAllFilters();
        };
```

Comment: @techprat it was a while ago and I don't have access to the code anymore (previous employment) so while this did work I can't remember the details of what I ended up modifying. Looking in the api doc I see the function clearAllFilters takes up to three arguments and if you look at the [code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/7a3669b/src/js/core/factories/Grid.js#L2504) you can see that depending on what behavior you want you may have to set these parameters to get expected results. So short answer is yes - but you may have to play with the parameters to get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this:

//get the grid api

```
$scope.myGridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
  $scope.myGridApi=gridApi;
}
```

You have to bind this function to your clear button :

```
        $scope.clearFilters = function() {
            var columns = $scope.myGridApi.grid.columns;
                for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    if (columns[i].enableFiltering) {
                        columns[i].filters[0].term='';
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: How do you capture the event?

Comment: but this will not clear the values selected on custom filter. Anyways this gets an upvote for best answer for this question on this thread.

Comment: adding columns[i].filters[0].listTerm=''; solved my problem of clearing selected filters as well.

Comment: Thank you for posting this @laurenOlga. I am wrestling with the same beast  as the new dev on the block, working with a very service, component and template heavy, rich application so it's a bit daunting. While I have not made significant progress yet, I just wanted to take some time to thank you for a very well thought-out and readable question!

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.clearAllFilters();
```

The $scope.gridApi was from the initial setting of my ui-grid element

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        flatEntityAccess: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        },
        columnDefs: [{
```

Comment: @ArepalliPraveenkumar: try the solution below by hic. it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simple way(just replacing the grid data with original/actual json data), you can simply create and call below clearFilters function on click of a button.

```
$scope.clearFilters = function() {
        $scope.yourGridOptions.data = $scope.originalData;
    }
```